# Serde conditionally deserialize each item in a sequence

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to write a deserializer for a vector of enum type `Command`. I want it to deserialize conditionally; if the unsigned byte value is less than 100 it is an `Element` and will be deserialized like any other `Vec<u8>`. Otherwise if the unsigned byte value is between 100 and 2^8, it is a Operation and will be deserialized as a `u8`. I have the following working implementation:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
bincode = "1.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.99" }
```

**main.rs**

```
use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Visitor, SeqAccess};
use bincode::{DefaultOptions, Options};
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Command {
    Operation(u8),
    Element(Vec<u8>)
}

struct VecVisitor;
impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for VecVisitor {
    type Value = Vec<Command>;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("Commands")
    }

    fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut seq: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error> where V: SeqAccess<'de>,
    {
        let length = seq.size_hint().unwrap();
        let mut commands: Vec<Command> = Vec::new();

        let mut count = 0;
        while count < length {
            count += 1;
            let current: u8 = seq.next_element()?.unwrap();
            match current {
                1..=100 => {
                    let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
                    for _ in 0..current {
                        v.push(seq.next_element()?.unwrap());
                    }
                    commands.push(Command::Element(v));
                    count += current as usize;
                }
                _ => {
                    commands.push(Command::Operation(current))
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(commands)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyVec(Vec<Command>);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyVec {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<MyVec, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Ok(MyVec(deserializer.deserialize_seq(VecVisitor)?))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bytes = vec![9u8, 150u8, 175u8, 3u8, 1u8, 2u8, 3u8, 2u8, 3u8, 2u8]; // 150 = Operation, 175 = Operation, 3 = Element, 2 = Element

    let commands: MyVec = DefaultOptions::new()
                    .with_varint_encoding()
                    .deserialize(&bytes).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", commands);
}
```

Output:

```
MyVec([Operation(150), Operation(175), Element([1, 2, 3]), Element([3, 2])])
```

Is there a more succinct way to write this?

I have tried replacing the `Element` parsing with the following, but it only works where the length of the vector is constant (for example `3`):

```
            match current {
                1..=100 => {
                    let v = seq.next_element::<[u8; 3]>()?.unwrap().to_vec();
                    commands.push(Command::Element(v));
                    count += current as usize;
                }
```

I think the best solution would be to somehow conditionally consume the next element in `seq` by peeking the next element for [`seq` (SeqAccess)](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.SeqAccess.html#method.next_element) and if the element is less than 100 it should deserialized as any other `Vec<u8>`.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think the loop here is fine since it makes your intent very clear. A better way to make the code succinct, and more idiomatic at the same time, is to get rid of `count` and replace it with a `while let` loop like this:

```
fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut seq: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error>
where
    V: SeqAccess<'de>,
{
    let mut commands: Vec<Command> = Vec::new();
    while let Some(current) = seq.next_element()? {
        match current {
            1..=100 => {
                let mut v = Vec::new();
                for _ in 0..current {
                    v.push(seq.next_element()?.unwrap());
                }
                commands.push(Command::Element(v));
            }
            _ => commands.push(Command::Operation(current)),
        }
    }
    Ok(commands)
}
```

If you really wanted to get rid of the loop, you could use an iterator and collect it into a vector (shown below) but I find this to be less clear and frankly unnecessary.

```
1..=100 => {
    commands.push(Command::Element(
        (0..current)
            .map(|_| seq.next_element().map(Option::unwrap))
            .collect::<Result<Vec<u8>, _>>()?,
    ));
}
```